# use HLS to implement Huffman coding from c

Tags: huffman-code, http-live-streaming, vivado

When I try to sythnise using the Vivado HLS, I get this errors about the unsynthesizable type.My project is about huffman coding.

```
@I [HLS-10] Starting code transformations ...
@I [HLS-10] Checking synthesizability ...
@E [SYNCHK-11] huff.c:17: Constant 'temp' has an unsynthesizable type '[13 x %struct.tnode.0.2.4]*' (possible cause(s): structure variable cannot be decomposed due to unsupported type conversion or memory copy operation).
@E [SYNCHK-11] huff.c:21: Constant 'ptemp' has an unsynthesizable type '[13 x %struct.tnode.0.2.4*]*' (possible cause(s): pointer to pointer or global pointer).
@E [SYNCHK-72] huff.c:24: unsupported c/c++ library function 'qsort'.
@E [SYNCHK-41] huff.c:38: unsupported pointer reinterpretation from type '%struct.tnode.0.2.4 = type { %struct.tnode.0.2.4*, %struct.t...' to type 'i8*' on variable 'ptemp'.
@E [SYNCHK-42] huff.c:47: pointer comparison is not supported.
@I [SYNCHK-10] 5 error(s), 0 warning(s).
@E [HLS-70] Synthesizability check failed.
```

And also have some difficult when doing the C sim.

```
    **..
...
@I [APCC-3] Tmp directory is apcc_db
@I [APCC-1] APCC is done.
@I [LIC-101] Checked in feature [VIVADO_HLS]
   Generating csim.exe
@E Simulation failed: SIGSEGV.
@E [SIM-1] CSim failed with errors.
4
    while executing
"source C:/Users/qijun/Desktop/Huff/hls/solution1/csim.tcl"
    invoked from within
"hls::main C:/Users/qijun/Desktop/Huff/hls/solution1/csim.tcl"
    ("uplevel" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"uplevel 1 hls::main {*}$args"
    (procedure "hls_proc" line 5)
    invoked from within
"hls_proc $argv"
@I [LIC-101] Checked in feature [VIVADO_HLS] **
```

Attachments include the code for my "top function".
I'm not experienced with HLS tools. Can somebody help me how I can fix this ? How can we include data structures in top function of vivado HLS ?
Thank you

Comment: It would be helpful if you put a short example code in your question that is causing the issue, and perhaps focus on a single question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you forgot to add the attachments or any code.

Second, I strongly recommend you to read at least a bit of the [Recommended Coding Styles](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2016_2/ug902-vivado-high-level-synthesis.pdf#nameddest=HighLevelSynthesisCodingStyles) from Xilinx's documentation, where they specifically explain that certain types of C constructs are unsupported, such as the ones you're seeing on your output.

So you might just want to refactor or recode part of your Huffman in order to fit those standards.